# How to force session_id in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing some ajax calls (with jquery) from browser.
I notice that the session id is not sent by the browser.
What I want to do is to pass the session ID as a parameter.
But on server side, i do not know how to tell asp.net "Now, you will use this value as session_id".

In PHP, i was used to do something like that:

```
   session_start($_POST['my_session_id']);
```

I want to do the same thing in ASP.Net

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to use custom session management to integrate an existing php site with your asp.net application, or are you asking how to just override how asp.net handles session identifiers?

Comment: Just override session identifiers

Comment: Can't you simply use cookies to pass your server-side sessionID on the client side, and then access it on the client by reading your cookie ? And setting cookie  on the serverside is a one-liner: **Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("my_Session_Id", "SUPER SECURE SESSION ID"));**

Comment: Yes but the problem is on the other side, when i will get my_Session_Id in header

Answer (score 0):

You want a custom [ISessionIdManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.isessionidmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The ISessionIDManager interface identifies the methods that you must implement to create a custom manager for session-identifier values. An ISessionIDManager interface implementation creates and validates session-identifier values, and manages the storage of a session identifier in the HTTP response as well as the retrieval of a session-identifier value from the HTTP request.
>
> [...]
>
> If you only want to supply custom session-identifier values to be used by ASP.NET session state, you can create a class that inherits the SessionIDManager class and override only the CreateSessionID and Validate methods with your own custom implementation. This enables you to supply your own session-identifier values, while relying on the base SessionIDManager class to store values to the HTTP response and retrieve values from the HTTP request.

Comment: I have tried to create my custom class but i did not manage to force session_id from post vars

Comment: Could you update your question with your implementation of CreateSessionID and any errors or problems you ran into?

Comment: Finaly, i wrote my own token management.
I do not understand why there is no way to do a simple session_id(xxx) like in PHP

Comment: Did you try a custom CreateSessionID implementation that read from `context.Request.Form['my_session_id']`?